# keeping the compiled project inside one common directory inside wwwroot folder

Tags: asp.net, iis

I don't know if you guys have face the same problem as mine. 
When I place my compiled web app inside `wwwroot`, everything works fine. 
Suppose my compiled web app has directories
`bin, view (contains aspx pages and master page file) then web config and packages.config files`.

Now if I place these files and folders just inside my `wwwroot` directory `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`  everything works fine. I can browse my web application.

But when I put these files and folders inside one common directory say `Project` such that now the file path become `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Project`

Now I get issues like 
`Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Project.view.AdminMaster'`. error with pre compiled classes. Why is it so ?

Comment: What else are you changing to accommodate the relocation of the content?   What files remain under c:\inetpub\wwwroot\?  Are you hoping for your URL to stay the same or to append Project at the end?

Comment: @Rich-Lang No I have not changed anything else. All the files and folders `bin, view, web config, packages config` are inside the `wwwroot` folder. For the case of URL, I just want to open my aspx pages via browser when the folder structure is `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Project`. Why I am having this problem?

Comment: @Rich-Lang According to this tutorial https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/280137/How-To-Deploy-a-Web-App-in-IIS should I have to change `Change the "CodeBehind" in the aspx file to "CodeFile".` ?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how you could produce the error you have.  Each of the different ways I'm considering how you could be doing this, wouldn't produce that error.  To beclear, you are moving all your content from wwwroot to wwwroot\project\ and then requesting the contents like http://hostname/project/myfile.aspx instead of http://hostname/myfile.aspx?

Comment: @Rich-Lang No I am try to browse the same way `http://www.ble.com/myfile.aspx`. This `http://www.ble.com` is the name of website I have given in IIS, while deploying. I changed the `CodeBehind` to `CodeFile` but still getting the error `Parser Error Message: The file '/AdminMaster.master.cs' does not exist.`

Comment: Does MyFile.aspx still reside under wwwroot?

Comment: No, its inside the `Project` folder

Comment: The if your site still points to wwwroot, I would an expect a call to hostname/myfile.aspx to result in a file not found.

Comment: @Rich-Lang Sorry I didn't understand what are you trying to say. Kindly explain. Thank You!!!

Comment: Your IIS site has a physical path that it points to.  For you this should be c:\inetpub\wwwroot\. When you make a request to www.ble.com/myfile.aspx, the first thing it does is look for a file under c:\inetpub\wwwroot\myfile.aspx .  If it doesnt find it, it would return 404.  If you've moved all the files to a project folder I wouldn't expect anything else to happened.

Comment: @Rich-Lang No I have pointed till `Project/view` since my aspx pages and master page is inside the view folder. So there is no question of file not found error.

Comment: Please clarify what your last comment was.  What other changes did you make?

Comment: `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Project\view` my `aspx` pages and `master page` are inside `view` folder. 
When deploying my web app in `IIS`, i have given the `phyiscal path` till `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Project\view`

Comment: I'm now confused by this "view" folder. When you deploy your content to c:\inetpub\wwwroot\ and the site works, are the ASPX files and Master Page files under a view folder then? And if so, how is the physical path configured, and what URL do you use to access the pages?

Comment: I'd move this to Chat if I had the reputation to do so.  At any rate.   Your Physical Path of your site needs to point to the root of your application.  This will be where your Web.config is, where your bin folder is, etc.   That's not negotiable.   You say you have ASPX pages under a View Folder which I can only assume means that during your "working" deployment you would have them under c:\inetpub\wwwroot\View\.   This then would mean your URL would be http://www.ble.com/view/MyFile.aspx.  This though is not what you said earlier.

Comment: @Rich-Lang do you have anydesk? I can show you the whole process if you agree to see my project configuration. Thank You!!!